# Error occurred during node.js deployment (Cloud9 -> Heroku)

Tags: node.js, deployment, heroku

```
1:: Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.156' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

-----&gt; Heroku receiving push
-----&gt; Node.js app detected
-----&gt; Resolving engine versions
   Using Node.js version: 0.6.8
   Using npm version: 1.1.41
-----&gt; Fetching Node.js binaries
-----&gt; Vendoring node into slug
-----&gt; Installing dependencies with npm
   npm WARN package.json cssom@0.2.3 No README.md file found!
   npm WARN package.json connect@1.8.5 No README.md file found!

   &gt; contextify@0.1.1 install /tmp/build_bofw5mh3ha0z/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
   &gt; node-gyp rebuild

   gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.8/node-v0.6.8.tar.gz
   gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.8/node-v0.6.8.tar.gz
   gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/tmp/build_bofw5mh3ha0z/.node-gyp/0.6.8'
   gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`, please file an Issue: 
   gyp ERR!     https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   npm ERR! contextify@0.1.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 7
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.1 install script.
   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-aT6q/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-o7eN/cli.js" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_bofw5mh3ha0z
   npm ERR! node -v v0.6.8
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.41
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! stack Error: contextify@0.1.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! stack `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 7
   npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
```